# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/AddCircle', but @mui/icons-material is installed

Tags: javascript, kotlin, webpack, material-ui

I write in kotlin JS (IR compiler). I get this error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/AddCircle'`

But `@mui/icons-material`  is installed.

I checked whether this module is installed. It is installed. Exactly. Then I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@mui and @material-ui are 2 different things

npm install @mui/icons-material --force

npm install --save material-ui-icons
  
if no any changes then try this

npm install @material-ui/core --force
npm install @material-ui/icons --force
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have already written that I am writing on kotlin. That is, my npm dependencies are managed by gradle. Can you tell me how to do this in gradle?

Comment: Thank you again. My problem was solved after executing the following code inside the `build/js` subdirectory inside my project:

`sudo npm i -g npm`, `npm install @mui/icons-material --force`, `npm audit fix --force`.

PS: It's strange, but I can't insert a valid example of multi-line code here.